# how config default.conf in nginx 1.13.3 for laravel 5.x

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

in nginx befor we change /etc/nginx/sites-available/default to

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/laravel/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name <Your Domain name / Public IP Address>;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

but in nginx 1.13.3 how we can place this changes?

Comment: Are you looking for default.conf? if so you can find it in /etc/nginx/conf.d or /etc/nginx/sites-available. it depends on which one is included in your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you worked with ubuntu before that's why You found the `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` directories because NGINX by it self doesn't have that in it's setup.  so you can either place your default configuration file directly in

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/default  #default is your configuration file
```

Or create `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and then edit the **http** block inside `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and add this line

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

all  files should be inside `sites-available` and then you create a symlink for them inside `sites-enabled`

Answer (score 0):

default file path: `/etc/nginx/sites-available`

You can create new file also there.

All you can checkout ngnix example default file for laravel: https://gist.github.com/sagarjethi/0993c21aa57d220cc90eb8d45cac66c5

```
server {
    #if single domain then uncomment following line
   # listen 80 default_server;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;  #add your domain name here

    access_log /var/www/laravel-example.com/logs/access.log; # change path as per your application
    error_log /var/www/laravel-example/logs/error.log;

    root /var/www/example.com/public;  #laravel application full path
    index index.php index.html;

    # serve static files directly
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # enforce NO www
    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
    {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
    }

    # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; # may also be: 127.0.0.1:9000;  this path is as your php version
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sagar, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)